# Wait to Display Text in React-Native Component

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a component that fetches data from an api, then will display the data on the screen.  What I would like to know, is how do I delay displaying the text on the screen until the api call is complete?

Ex:

`Your Balance is ____`

after network call resolves

`Your Balance is 500`

but `"Your Balance is"` displays as soon as the component is rendered.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import {StyleSheet, View, Text} from 'react-native'

export default class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      accountBalance: ''
    };

    fetch('someURL', {method: "GET"})  
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
        this.setState({
          accountBalance: responseData.amount
        })
      })
      .done();

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={{color: '#FFF'}}> Your Account Balance is {this.state.accountBalance} </Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 10,
    paddingTop: 74,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }
})
```

Comment: Don't delay anything, but don't display `Your Balance is` on page load either... show a loading indicator

Comment: ya good point.  Trying to get used to thinking in mobile design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you could do something as simple as returning `null` when there is no balance:

```js
render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {this.state.accountBalance ? (
        <Text style={{color: '#FFF'}}> Your Account Balance is {this.state.accountBalance} </Text>
      ) : null}
    </View>
  )
}
```

You could track the request using a separate state variable as well, such as `this.state.balanceLoaded: false` and return `null` until that changes.  You then would update that value to `true` in your `fetch` callback.  This would solve issues where the value was returned but *falsy*, such as `''` or `0`